# How to figure out why I'm getting "HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code"?

Tags: 2010, error, debugging

I am brand new to SharePoint, SharePoint development, and MS development.

My SharePoint dev environment consists of Windows 2008, SharePoint 2010, and Visual Studio 2010.

I created a very simple "Hello World" Visual WebPart, deployed it to SharePoint through Visual Studio, added it to a new page, and was able to view it with no problem.

I then enhanced the WebPart by adding a few controls and some code.  When I deployed the Web Part, and went to the page containing it, I received an error in Visual Studio: **"HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code"**.

I then erased all of my new code, so that the XXXUserControl.ascx file contains only a single button and the XXXUserControl.ascx.cs file contains only an empty Page_Load method.  I deployed again, but received the same error.

I'm looking either for an explanation of what's happening, or tips on how to debug.

**Details:**

The error is: "HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code"

The error occurs in the auto-generated XXXWebPart.cs file on the line marked with "<-----" below:

```
namespace UserSyncTest1.UserSyncTest1WebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class UserSyncTest1WebPart : WebPart
    {
        // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/UserSyncTest1/UserSyncTest1WebPart/UserSyncTest1WebPartUserControl.ascx";

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);  <-----
            Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
}
```

The output window contains:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Answer (score 1):

The error can relate to a lot of things:

File (ASCX) is not valid: Create

- a new visual webpart, then compare the 2 ascx files, a small typo like a
  < or > to much can break a file
- Did you change any project settings: Target framework (can't be 4.0), Deployment type (Sandbox or Farm)
- Server ran out of memory and stopped compiling (Check the eventlogs)
- SharePoint is "broken" i.e. SharePoint's Virtual Path Provider is looking for the ascx in the wrong place: delete webapp, reboot, then recreate webapp + sitecollection and redeploy

Answer (score 0):

In UserCode solution type, you can't refer to the disk (in this case, the LoadControl will have an IO on the server, to the file /_CONTROLTEMPLATES/UserSyncTest1/UserSyncTest1WebPart/UserSyncTest1WebPartUserControl.ascx).

You should, or make a Farm Solution, or generate your HTML from your control, in code, not in declarative way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, this bit of code (in fact the whole XXXWebPart.cs file) is auto-generated by Visual Studio.  It looks like SharePoint does in fact put the ascx file at that location as part of deploying the Web Part.

Comment: I understand that the code is auto-generated.  But you surely can't use ascx in a user code solution.  You change this setting in your project properties.  The UserCode solutions (Sandbox) are protected from using any IO.  This is the error you are getting.

Comment: But why did the web part initially work?  Also, what setting should I try changing?

Comment: It could work if the webpart was in Farm Solution mode.  You can change it in your project properties.